# UISwitch showing values

Tags: ios, uikit, uiswitch

Does anyone know the setting that would control a UISwitch including the value in the display of the switch?

For example:  [image]

Notice the 1 in the on state.

Comment: BTW - this isn't actually a programming question. This is a general "how to use iOS" question.

Comment: Agreed, was thinking it might be in the storyboard somewhere in 9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is one of the accessibility settings.

Settings app -> General -> Accessibility -> On/Off Labels

This is not something you can control via code in your app. This is something the user can choose to use or not and it affects all apps.